# Check whether the function is a solution to the ODE - $y'=-y^2$ in $(0,2)$, $D(X)=\frac 1 {x+2}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I dont know how to even start..
I know how to do solution of O.D.E exercises, but this way of question, it is the first time I see such a thing...
All I thought is that I have to make derivative for the $D(X)$, I will receive: $$-\frac{1}{\left(x+2\right)^2} = D'(X)$$
and I do for the $$D(X) = \frac{1}{\left(x+2\right)}$$
just increase power of it and I will receive:
$$D^2(X) = \frac{1}{\left(x+2\right)^2}$$

Which is: $D'(X) \ne D^2(X)$
Am I correct in my solution? the way of question is a first timer, so got in trouble a little.

Comment: If the equation is $y'=-y^{2}$ (as in your title)  then $D(X)$ is a  solution.

Comment: @geetha290krm yea, that is the equation.
But why is it a solution, I will receive -1 = 1 which is not true.

Comment: ohh forgot from the minus... I am stupid.. Thanks